# UITapGestureRecognizer recognizing tap after scaling UIView

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIView` which I scale to 4x after tapping on it. It works fine. On the next tap I want to restore it back to original size. The problem is that it recognizes the tap only in the smaller rectangle the `UIView` had before scaling. I would like to recognize the tap anywhere in the scaled `UIView`. How can I achieve it?

```
//Tapping code
titleCard = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: myrect];
[self addSubview:titleCard];
[titleCard release];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(changeSize:)];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[titleCard addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
[tapRecognizer release];

//Scaling code
CABasicAnimation *scale = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
[scale setBeginTime:CACurrentMediaTime()+0.75];
[scale setDuration:0.5];
[scale setToValue: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:4.0f]];
[scale setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
[scale setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what does not work over here, i replaced the below code.

```
//Scaling code 
CABasicAnimation *scale = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"]; 
[scale setBeginTime:CACurrentMediaTime()+0.75]; 
[scale setDuration:0.5]; 
[scale setToValue: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:4.0f]]; 
[scale setRemovedOnCompletion:NO]; 
[scale setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
[titleCard.layer addAnimation:scale forKey:@"Scale"];
```

with

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Scale" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0.75];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

[titleCard setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(4.0f, 4.0f);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Now the clicks are getting recognized all over the `UIView` and not just the smaller rectangle before the scaling happened.

Comment: The reason this works is that the gesture is based on the size of your view. When you animate the layer you are changing the visuals but you are not actually changing the size of the view.

Your replacement code does actually change the size of the view.

Answer (score -1):

its always recognizes all the tap as similar 
here u can put the any counter value like

static NSInteger *counter=0;

now make it 1 if count is equal to 0 and make it 0 if count is equal to 1

now on basis of value of count u can zoom in and zoom out.

Comment: Hi Ajay, I understood the point. Scaling is not an issue for me. Only getting a call in the selector is. The problem with me is that i set a breakpoint in the selector. I always get a call when the image is not scaled. Now i scale the image after first tap. After that i do not receive a call at all on any number of taps on the scaled image. But when only when i click in that small rectangle in the big scaled image which the UIView was actually showing before scaling, it gets hit.

Comment: tap event is normally not call on  image for that u have to make that image touchable   use  this code:                             -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch view] == yourImageView)
    {
            //add your code for image touch here 
    }

}